# Differentiating and proving equation FM Pure

Tags: derivatives

I am seriously unable to just prove this equation. I end up with x^3's always and am unable to proceed just after differentiating it. I tried thinking of binomial theorem but it would only help in decreasing the power more and more. So I am seriously out of ideas. Please share the compete answer! Thank you!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PEhJ.jpg)

Comment: Please put the relevant info *in the question*, and at the very least, provide an image that is not rotated and taken in a dark catacomb.

Comment: Sorry. First time user, actually. Let me edit it and just put the relevant part...

Comment: (1) You should upload directly the question here, without links...or even better: write down directly the question. (2) If you give a link, **at least** take care the image is upside up!

Comment: @LordAbys007 It's alright, that's why I commented. Let us know when that's done and we'll see what we can do for you.

Comment: @The Count Is it okay now? I wrote it by myself so that it becomes clear.

Comment: Yeah, that's better. In the future, it would behoove you to write it using MathJaX formatting, which is easy to learn.

Comment: Let's just look at the left side. What rule do you think you will need to use to differentiate this?

Comment: The product rule, of course.

Comment: @The Count Did I miss anything?

Comment: Ok, good. What would that first step look like? (be sure to use the @ feature to ping me so I see it!)

Comment: @Don Antonio I just corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the product rule:

$$\left[x(1+x^3)^{-n}\right]'=1\cdot(1+x^3)^{-n}+x(-n)3x^2(1+x^3)^{-n-1}=$$

$$=(1+x^3)^{-n-1}\left[1+x^3-3nx^3\right]=\color{red}{(1+x^3)^{-n-1}\left[1+(1-3n)x^3\right]}$$

Or you can apply the quotient rule:

$$\left(\frac x{(1+x^3)^n}\right)'=\frac{1\cdot(1+x^3)^n-x\cdot3nx^2(1+x^3)^{n-1}}{(1+x^3)^{2n}}=$$

$$=\color{red}{\frac{1+x^3-3nx^3}{(1+x^3)^{n+1}}}$$

You can make sure both final expressions above are the same

**Added** Observe the right hand of the expression you were given is

$$-(3n-1)(1+x^3)^{-n}+3n(1+x^3)^{-n-1}=-\frac{3n-1}{(1+x^3)^n}+\frac{3n}{(1+x^3)^{n+1}}=$$

$$=\frac1{(1+x^3)^n}\left[-3n+1+\frac{3n}{1+x^3}\right]=\frac1{(1+x^3)^n}\left[\frac{(1-3n)x^3+1-3n+3n}{1+x^3}\right]=$$

$$=\frac{(1-3n)x^3+1}{(1+x^3)^{n+1}}$$

Comment: @ DonAntonio thank you very much for writing all of this down which is exactly correct. But it still does not equal to the R.H.S of the equation. That's the problem; I came this far but couldn't go any further...

Comment: @LordAbys007 It is **exactly the same** . Just work a little on the right hand of the equation they gave you and verify it is exaclty the same as both final answers above. Why they gave you that differential in *that weird form* I've no idea...but it indeed is the same. :)

Comment: Thank you very much! @DonAntonio I must say, I had no idea that I just had to go a little further to prove it! Thank you very much, again!

Comment: @LordAbys007 Any time. It is always advisable, imo, to try to write down algebraic expressions in several different equivalente ways. Some give us insights in this, others in that...